# Replacing OnAddGeofencesResultListener and OnRemoveGeofencesResultListener with OnSuccessListener

Tags: java, android, geofencing

I'm trying to update an old Geofencing app to use the new Geofencing API (based on `GeofencingClient`), instead of the old API (based on `LocationClient` - deprecated and removed). The old app/API implements `OnAddGeofencesResultListener` and `OnRemoveGeofencesResultListener` interfaces, while the new app/API implements `OnCompleteListener<Void>` and/or `OnSuccessListener<Task<Void>>`.

The callback functions of the **old interface** passes **`PendingIntent`** and **`GeofenceRequestIds`** (which is `string[]`), in addition to the `int statusCode`, as arguments:

- `@Override public void onAddGeofencesResult(int statusCode, String[] geofenceRequestIds)`
- `@Override public void onRemoveGeofencesByPendingIntentResult(int statusCode, PendingIntent requestIntent)`
- `@Override public void onRemoveGeofencesByRequestIdsResult(int statusCode, String[] geofenceRequestIds)`

***Question***: Is there a way to access **PendingIntent** and **GeofenceRequestIds** from the callbacks of the **new interface** (e.g., the Task or an override)?

- `@Override public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)`
- `@Override   public void onSuccess(@NonNull Task<Void> voidTask)`

I have been using these arguments to log and send the info to other components of the app.